# How to cc a user in System.Net.Mail.MailMessage using powershell script?

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-2.0, sendmail, powershell-3.0

I have a code written to generate a report file in HTML format using a powershell.

Used the below code to send an email with that HTML as an attachment.
But unable to cc the user to the mail.

**Code:**

```
$subject = "Subject Line" 
$body = Get-Content "D:\temp\ABC\TEST\report.htm" 
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
$smtp.send($msg)
```

Could someone please suggest me on how to send cc using the above syntax?

I can use the `Send-MailMessage` to accommodate the cc list.But in that case i wouldn't be able to send the HTML output as a body message.

Comment: could someone please help me in getting the bottom of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

MailMessage has a property called CC that you can set like you set the To line. `$msg.CC = "whatever@wherever.somedomain"`. Send-MailMessage has a -BodyAsHtml switch.  Pick your poison.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've already tried this $msg.cc.Ad(...) which didnt work.Though the powershell completes without any error,email doesnt get delivered to the cc list.Could you please hlp me in getting the -bodyAsHtml switch for the Send-MailMessage or may the syntax for adding $msg.cc  ?

Comment: I used $msg.CC.Add("some@someother.com") and then ran $msg and the output showed the CC line populated - does that happen to you when you look at yours and you're adding it before you're sending it, right?  I know that's a silly question...

Comment: Yes that does print..but the actual email is not sent to the cc listed member.May i request you to help me with the option you have suggested for send-MailMessage to have the bodyAsHtml flag set to true?

Answer (score 1):

you should read the help file  and is already have pretty nice examples.

```
Get-Help Send-MailMessage -Examples
```

If you are not getting any examples, do `Update-Help`

```
Send-MailMessage -To 'to@email.com' -From 'from@email.com' -Cc 'cc@email.com'  -body $bodyhtml -BodyAsHtml
```

Regards

kvprasoon